# Updating Fields in a Table with Values from Query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm struggling to understand why my event code for updating a Microsoft Access form field is only half working.

I have a query, we'll call DataQuery, that selects 3 column values from what we'll call Table1 that looks like the following:

```
**Part**       **Description**       **Revision**
10-123             Descrip1             A
10-342             Descrip2             D
10-232             Descrip3             E
```

I have another table where I'd like to assign the values from description and revision to fields in another table, we'll call Table2, based on picking a value in a combo box.

For instance:

We select a value of 10-342 in our combo box, then the values "Descrip2" and "D" get assigned to fields in Table2.

I can get this to work for whatever column I have in position one, but not position two.

My small vba code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox_AfterUpdate()

    Me.DescriptionField_Table2 = Me.ComboBox.Column(1)
    Me.RevisionField_Table2 = Me.ComboBox.Column(2)
    Me.Requery

End Sub
```

Where "ComboBox" row source is DataQuery mentioned previously.

As stated, "Me.DescriptionField_Table2 = Me.ComboBox.Column(1)" works as intended, but the second line seems to be getting ignored. I feel like I'm missing something super simple here, but I'm can't figure it out.

Comment: Set property _ColumnCount_ of the combobox to 3.

Comment: Why duplicate descriptive info into another table? Just save Part value or an autonumber primary key. Retrieve related info in query joining tables.

Comment: @June7 To give you some insight, I'm trying to pull the info into a subform where I would like to display the revision and description. I'll note that this may still not be the best way to do it, but the only thing I could figure out was to add a column in the subform's table such that it gets updated.

Comment: @Gustav This worked! Thank you so much. I knew it was easy.

Comment: Expression in textbox can reference columns of combobox in order to display the descriptive values. No VBA and no data duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knew this was something simple...

[Gustav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3527297/gustav), in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60021253/updating-fields-in-a-table-with-values-from-query/60021845#comment106150607_60021253), answered my issue:

> Set property ColumnCount of the combobox to 3.

Comment: On this occasion there was no other answer to accept. I've edited the self-answer to include the comment, with attribution.